# 2d array using a double pointer and malloc function

Tags: c, pointers

i am trying to create a 2d array using  double pointer...
my code is...

---

```
int **p1;
p1=(int **) malloc(2*sizeof(int *));
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    p1[i]=(int *) malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
       scanf("%d",(p1+i)+j);
    }

}
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{

    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
       printf("%d\n",*(*(p1+i)+j));
    }

}
```

---

as i have declared a double pointer (**p1) for it and i am able to put data at all those places using my scan `scanf("%d",(p1+i)+j);` statement. And to dereference i can use print statement as i have done `printf("%d\n",*(*(p1+i)+j));`

but why it is breaking during print statement but accepting my scan statement.

but why this is giving me correct response...

```
int mybox[][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}};//we have to provide subscript;
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        printf("%d",mybox[i][j]);//will print all elements
        }
}
        printf("%d",*(*(mybox)+1));//give me 2
        printf("%d",*(*(mybox+1)+1));//give me 6
        printf("%d",*(*(mybox+1)+3));//give me 8
```

Comment: "why is it breaking" -- What is the error message?

Comment: **An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in myapp.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: @cnicutar actually i m working on visual studio 2010 express

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `scanf` portion is implemented incorrectly. It destroys your data. Ironically, the problem does not reveal itself during `scanf` phase, but instead causes a crash at `printf` stage.

The correct `scanf` code might look as follows

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    p1[i]=(int *) malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
       scanf("%d",*(p1+i)+j);
    }
}
```

Note the extra `*`. What you really need here is

```
scanf("%d", &(*(*(p1 + i)) + j));
```

You can write it this way if you want. But you can notice that the outer `&` "annihilates" with the next nested `*`, so the above is equivalent to

```
scanf("%d", *(p1 + i) + j);
```

However, my advice to you is to stop using the barely-readable `*-and-+` combination for array element access and start using the `[]` instead. This is how your code should have looked from the very beginning

```
...
scanf("%d", &p1[i][j]);
...
printf("%d\n", p1[i][j]);
```

On top of that, since this is taggged C, avoid using `sizeof` with types as much as possible and stop casting the result of `malloc`. A better variant would be

```
int **p1;

p1 = malloc(2 * sizeof *p1);
for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
{
  p1[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof *p1[i]);
  ...
```

Comment: p1 is a pointer to pointer then how can i dereference it using only 1 *

Comment: becuase int this you are looking for a pointer, not for a value pointed by a pointer

Comment: can you suggest me good article to learn double pointer and 2d arrays

Comment: @teacher: I added the explanation for "only one *" to the answer.

Comment: @teacher: The problem with typecasting is that it is completely unnecessary and can be dangerous (see here http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html). When you use `sizeof` operator, it is better to use it with expressions instead of type names. That way your code becomes more type-independent. It becomes easier to maintain. (Imagine you need to change `int` to `double`. How many places you'd need to fix in your version and in mine?).

Comment: @Andrey error is **myapp.cpp(287): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'int **'**

Comment: @teacher: The error message you quoting will usually appear in **C++** code. You tagged your question as **C**. You need to decide which language you are actually using: C or C++. My answer applies to C and only to C.

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%d",(p1+i)+j);
```

This is wrong, and not what you expect. Associativity says that a+b+c == (a+b) + c == a + (b+c).

Avoid direct pointer arithmetic because it is hell confusing when you are new to the language. Prefer:

```
   scanf("%d", &p1[i][j]);

   printf("%d\n", p1[i][j]);
```

The generated assembly code is exactly the same as if you went for direct pointer arithmetic.

Also, unrelated but important, do not cast the return type of malloc(), as this may hide potential bugs in your code (like the lack of a `#include <stdlib.h>`, which is very important).

---

Keep in mind that the types `int**` and `int[][N]` are quite different in their implementation. Assumptions made for one are not true for the other, even though you can access the elements using the same `var[i][j]` syntax.

Your second example gives the correct answer because it is... correct? That is it. The second example doesn't have any scanf(), which is where your problem is in the first example.

Comment: thank you sir but can you explain how to achieve same results using pointer not "p1[i][j]"

Comment: You could have passed `*(p1+i)+j` to sscanf() (note the leading `*`, because you want to derreference the result of the `p1+i` pointer to get the other pointer before adding `j` to it). But **don't do that**, since it makes your code less readable. Again, just say exactly what you want to say. You want to pass the address of `p1[i][j]` to sscanf(), then just say it with a `&` in front.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a 2d array where all data is stored in adjacent memory cells on the heap (as opposed to the ** syntax more commonly seen). It uses the concept of *array pointers* which you can read about in the [C lang FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

```
int (*ptr)[X]; 
ptr = malloc(X * Y * sizeof(int));
```

And yes, you can use the ptr[x][y] if you malloc in this way.

Comment: Yes, but this is only possible when X is a compile-time constant. If so, the recommended and much more elegant way to allocate memory would be `ptr = malloc(Y * sizeof *ptr);`.

Comment: I agree, although that will not make the [][] syntax possible, which the OP asked for.

Comment: Er... I don't see what you mean. An array allocated as shown above will be perfectly accessible as `ptr[i][j]`. The only difference in my comment is how the size is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d\n",(*(p1+i)+j));
```

replace your scanf for taking the array values...